# How do I install Boot Camp drivers without installing Boot Camp

Tags: boot-camp, drivers, isight

I am using Skype on Windows XP Pro (SP3) that is running quite well on a VMware Fusion virtual machine.

Skype tells me that I need to install the Apple Boot Camp Drivers for the iN-sight Web Camera that I am using.

I have used Skype slightly without the Boot camp driver, with no problems so far. But, the warning indicates that there might be problems.  Installing the driver might avert a problem in the future - but I cannot figure out how to install the drivers without installing Boot Camp - which I do not want to do

Answer (score 2):

To install the Apple hardware drivers:

1. Insert the Mac OS X Installation DVD into the Mac's optical drive.

   Note: Mac OS 10.5 (Leopard) or later is required. For Windows 7, Mac OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard) is required.
2. Open Fusion.
3. Start the Windows virtual machine.
4. Mount the DVD drive to the virtual machine:

   1. Go to Virtual Machine > CD/DVD, and select Connect CD/DVD if available.
   2. Go to Virtual Machine > CD/DVD, and select Use Physical CD/DVD Drive, if it is not   already selected.
5. After starting Windows, the DVD automatically launches if Autorun is enabled. Close this autorun window.
6. From the Windows desktop, open ( My) Computer.
7. Ctrl-click WindowsSupport (CD/DVD Drive), then click Explore.
8. Navigate to D:\Boot Camp\Drivers\ .
9. Double-click setup.exe to launch the Boot Camp drivers setup wizard. (The wizard automatically selects and installs the 32-bit or 64-bit drivers based on your Operating System.

   Note: The Boot Camp drivers setup wizard will only work in the Boot Camp–supported OSes: Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7 (32- bit) (Boot Camp 3–only). For other Operating Systems, including Windows 7 (64-bit), you must install the drivers individually (see below).
10. Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the install process.

    1. If you see a warning that This program has known compatibility issues, click Run program.
    2. Be sure to install the Apple Software Update, so that you are notified of any updates to these drivers.
11. Restart the virtual machine when prompted.

It is also possible to install individual drivers, to enable individual devices or gain additional functionality.

To install individual drivers:

1. Mount and explore the DVD by repeating steps 1-8 from above.
2. Open the sub-directory for your device, then find and run the correct installer for your device and Operating System. (The installer files for the Apple devices are listed below. )
3. Follow the on-screen instructions for the installer.
4. Restart the virtual machine when prompted.

Reference: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1012885

Comment: Yes, but what if you don't have a recent OSX installation DVD? After all, it is quite common these days to upgrade software via internet...

Comment: @PQA - Have you searched -https://www.apple.com/ca/support/bootcamp/ ?

Comment: @PQA - You can also check the answer over at apple.stackexchange: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24118/how-to-download-bootcamp-drivers-without-bootcamp-assistant My answer here is a bit outdated now anyways (2010) - Hope my 2 comments point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions given by Apple at http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5634 (thanks for the pointer @ricbax). I tried both direct download and using Boot Camp Assistant. In both cases I got an error message when trying to install the drivers in Windows 8.1 using Setup.exe:

> This version of bootcamp is not intended for this computer model

However, in the folder E:\BootCamp\Drivers of the download, it is possible to run individual driver installers, and in a way maybe that's better. Just install the drivers you need, and no unnecessary clutter.

This is actually indicated in @ricbax' answer from 2010, but I'm adding it here anyway since it doesn't match Apple's instructions, dated Oct 17, 2014, which I tried to follow.